# list of records without childs

Tags: trigger, relationships, childrecords

am very new to coding stuff and I am creating a trigger to count the total number of child accounts and the total number of dependent child account with some code that I found in this page to emulate the rollupsummary field behaviour in lookup relationship.
The first part is working fine but for the second part I need to get the accounts that does not have licenses(child object of account with lookup relationship). I did the stuff below but it is doing just the opposite :(

```
List<License__c> lics = [SELECT account__c from license__c where Active__c=True];
List<account> accwlic= null;

for(account a :Trigger.new){
            for (license__c l:lics){
                if (a.id==l.account__c)
                    accwlic.add(a);
            }            
        }
```

Also I was thinking in use somehow this kind of queries

```
SELECT Account.Name,(SELECT Id FROM Licenses__r active__c=true) FROM Account
```

But I will get the same result just the opposite.

Could you help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a set.

```
Set<Id> licencsedAccountIds = new Set<Id>();
for (License__c license : [SELECT Account_c FROM License__c WHERE Active__c = true])
{
    licensedAccountIds.add(license.Account__c);
}

for (Account newAccount : newAccounts)
{
    if (!licensedAccountIds.contains(newAccount.Id)) { /*Bingo!*/ }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't query for things that are not there, but that's easy to find. Just build a map, then iterate over your list and grab the results. Here's how:

```
Map<Id, AggregateResult> licenseCount = new Map<Id, AggregateResult>(
    [SELECT Account__c Id, COUNT(Id) Count 
     FROM License__c WHERE Active__c = true AND Account__c IN :Trigger.new]
);
for(Account record: Trigger.new) {
    if(licenseCount.containsKey(record.Id)) {
        record.Active_Licenses__c = (Decimal)licenseCount.get(record.Id).get('Count');
    } else {
        record.Active_Licenses__c = 0;
    }
}
```